# Possible to get Ubuntu to see Fujitsu SAS controller (LSI Logic SAS1068E)?

Tags: scsi

Is it possible to get Ubuntu to see Fujitsu SAS controller?

On Windows I think the Intel C600 drivers made the hardware visible, but I cannot seem to be able to find Intel C600 drivers for Ubuntu.

What to do?

It's also seen by `lspci`:

```
02:00.0 SCSI storage controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic SAS1068E PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS (rev 08)
```

But the drives attached to it aren't visible.

Comment: You should probably check the [Fujitsu documentation](https://sp.ts.fujitsu.com/dmsp/Publications/public/osrel-py.pdf) to determine if they have a driver for Ubuntu, for your hardware.  Knowing which model SAS that you have, would help!

Comment: @CharlesGreen See the output from `lspci`.

Comment: Interesting - the device is actually an LSI device, packaged with the manufacturers of several brands of servers.  There is some [older Debian documentation](https://wiki.debian.org/LinuxRaidForAdmins) about using the RAID devices, but little that seems current.  Also some very old information on [UbuntuForums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=933467)

Comment: After some poking about, there are two good possibilities for drivers.  You could try `sudo modprobe mtpsas` and `sudo modprobe mtp3sas` to determine if either of these is compatible with your device.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it seems that the driver for this was already included in Ubuntu.

As I speculated that it should be, if the hardware is seen by `lspci`.

The problem was that I was using the wrong port. The card has two ports that each split to 4x SCSI. And it seems as if the other one is treated as "primary" by the driver. I.e. if one uses only one of the ports, then it must be the primary one and not the other one.